# React-native - Pulsating Image / SVG

Tags: react-native, animation

Is it possible to pulsating a SVG in a Component? And how can i do this?
I found some packages but pulsating a circle, i want to pulsating a bag (SVG)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg) allows you to import SVGs (with some setup), or you can use its primitives to convert an SVG to RN components. Then to animate it, use [React Native's Animated API](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated). The fade in/out example on the API page can be easily adapted to make a pulsing animation.

Comment: My SVG is now pulsating, but not in the app. Must i take some configurations for this? I set :hermes_enabled to true in my Podfile and run "pod install"

Comment: That's good you've got something working. But when you say it's not working in the app, how do you mean?

Comment: If i open my SVG in a browser, everythings works fine. If i open the app, the SVG is not pulsating. I had this case a few years ago with a GIF. I had to enable support for it in the app. Do I need to do this for SVGs as well?

Comment: If you don't plan to import many SVGs then it's probably best just to use the SVG primitives from react-native-svg, `Circle`, `Rect`, etc.  This is a very handy tool for converting from an SVG to react-native-svg primitives: https://transform.tools/svg-to-react-native.  Otherwise you'll need to configure Metro to bundle them https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg/blob/main/USAGE.md#use-with-svg-files.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that and get back to you afterwards.

Comment: I will add a answer to my question, because the answer is too long :)

Comment: Looking at react-native-svg and it doesn't appear to support `animateTransform` https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg/issues/1019

Comment: Thanks for that, if i run this ode, everything works, but i dont know how i can add my SVG code for this to pulsate my SVG. Maybe you can help me with that